# Cucumber Test Runner file-Not executing step definitions

Tags: eclipse, junit, cucumber

I am building a Restassured API test framework with cucumber.(This is a new adventure for me so apologies if this seems basic)

Below is how I setup my test runner file.

```
package cucumber.Options;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features="src/test/java/features", glue={"stepDefinitions"},strict=true,stepNotifications = true)
public class TestRunner{
    
}
```

I have made sure the glue matches my step def file, ive also tried adding the full path.

However my step definitions no matter what I set as the glue are not being executed.

As soon as I run the TestRunner File as a junit test junit marks the runs as complete.

I set up a simple scenario where I am just printing a test output to console and console never shows the output.

I even tried setting my glue to a filename that doesnt even exist to see if i got an error but i get the same result as above.

And whenever I click one of the the lines in the feature file I get error "Test class not found in selected project"
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lihkf.png)

Has anyone experienced the same behavior with eclipse?

Comment: Why are you using junit insted of TestNG?
how did you cinvert feature file to step definations file?
what about you r test runner class?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about the structure of your project, the dependencies and version(s) you are using as well as how you are running your tests? Please add this information to your original question. In addition, I'd recommend starting your project based on the [10 minute tutorial](https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/) or the [cucumber-java-skeleton](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton) to start with a working project and expand from there.